# Maven Dependency's dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3

In my project I have slf4j-log4j12

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This version uses log4j 1.2.17. The log4j latest update is 2.11.1. 
How can I make my maven project to force use the latest log4j i.e. 2.11.1 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that log4j version 2 is completely incompatible with log4j version 1. You cannot replace like that those version.

To use log4j-2 as backend for slf4j, you will need to replace this dependency by another.

From [the page in log4j 2 site](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/), the dependency is linked to the version of slf4j

In your use case, (sf4j 1.7) it is this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

for slf4j 1.8+ it will be this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```